# How to replace or update query param in route URL?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I want to replace or update the second param of a URL.

My URL is this way edit/id/test-page/id2. I want to replace/update the value of id2 when a button is clicked. I tried the following but few of them are adding new query params to the existing URL, and one example was appending the value to id param.

1. `this.activatedoute.navigate([ this.route.url ], { queryParams: {id: this.id1, id2: this.id2} })`
2. `this.activatedoute.navigateByUrl(this.route.url);`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and errors, I have found the solution

```
constructor(private router: Router)

test(id2){
  this.router.navigate([`/edit/${this.id}/test-page`, id2]);
}
```